# Custom Font w/ @font-face: Rendering Differently on Windows and OS X

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I've been experiencing a problem with my custom font I included on my site.
Here are three pictures to demonstrate the differences between how this font is rendered (based on OS).

Windows 7
[image]

OS X Mavericks (non-retina)
[image]

OS X Yosemite (retina)
[image]

Now, as you can see, the last two images render fine. The problem I'm experiencing is that the first image (Windows 7) has an odd issue with certain characters, such as "t" and "f". The only way I found to fix this was to make the font 1px larger (as the current font-size is 13px). However, doing this would require me to redesign a large part of my site.

I have included the code for the `@font-face` below, along with some additional CSS.
http://paste2.org/WFmgF1Lw

Is there some CSS attribute I can add so that my font renders correctly on the Windows OS? If not, is there a way to fix this issue without having to increase the font size of every element that uses this font-face?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, this is not a css issue. Fonts are actually a pain in the ass. A major pain... As the way fonts render differ on OS'es and even browsers on the same OS. Make a little trip on google and you'll get scared... Especially custom fonts are terrible, so if you want to have the best results; buy a proper font that is cross-tested, or use a service like google fonts or fonts.com.

Comment: @giorgio Is there a way to fix the font itself rather than use a different font?

Comment: The most common problem is that a font misses type-hinting. You could use an automatic typehinter, use fontquirrel.org to do optimizations for you, or you could hire a font designer who does it manually. Unfortunately there is no way to get a near-perfect result automatically (that's also pretty much the reason fonts are so expensive...).

Comment: In my live I've ruined a lot of days struggling with fonts. Nowadays I refuse to use fonts that aren't properly hinted etc, or my client just has to be satisfied with a not-so-good result. Both of which I can explain pretty well to them. My advise would be: find an alternative font which looks like the one you are using... And explain your client (if you have any) that this font cannot be used unless he's willing to put 2000 bucks extra into the project.

Comment: @giorgio Thanks for the suggestion! I used the TTFAutohint option on the FontSquirrel font-face creator, and it seemed to have fixed the problem! It did tweak some other characters (minor), but I'm pretty satisfied with how it looks now. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with fontsquirrel's autohinting; I've seen fonts that came out looking worse than what they started out with. So make sure the results are as you like it, before publishing.

Comment: and note that both the Adobe FDK and Font Forge are free, both of which come with excellent autohinters.